# Click or Select inside WebView not working after using GestureDetector

Tags: android, webview, swipe, gesture

I am using `webView` inside a fragment, with following settings-

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.canGoBackOrForward(0);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.clearCache(true);
```

My web-page which is loaded in this webView, requires javascript, i.e. on clicking a button inside web-page does some work. It does work as it supposed to be if I use above mentioned as such. But I also want `webView` to detect `Gesture` like Swipe to Left/Right, so I tried using `GestureDetector` as follows -

```
final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "onDown from gesture");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "onFling has been called!");
        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Right to Left");
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Left to Right");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
});

webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

This `GestureDetector`, does detect Right/Left swipes, but **now normal clicking inside webView does not work**, which is required for javascript to work inside loaded web-page.

**So, how to make both (Normal clicking detection for javascript and `GestureDetector`) work simultaneously?**

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @shine_joseph unfortunately no, i couldn't find any working solution

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283056/how-to-have-both-swipe-and-touch-events-for-webview), replace:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

with:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
        return v.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain whaat is happening here and what is the diference

Comment: In the first code, the onTouchEvent function of the view is not called