# How to have both swipe and touch events for WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

Hello guys i am creating epub reader and i have customised my `WebView` to scroll horizontal, now i want to stop the default scroll and do scrolling programatically based on swipe guestures  i have already acheive it  like this way

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

  }
 }
```

and in my main activity

```
 webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeLeft() {
                            // my code to scroll previous page

                            }

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeRight() {
                            //my code to scroll next page
                        }
                    });
```

now the problem stated, i cannot have the default feature of `WebView` on longpress selecting text, how can i have swiping events  and still get the text selection feature on long press?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your implementation of `onTouch()`, the `onTouchEvent()` method of the `View` will not be called, preventing its default touch behaviour to run.

Change the following:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

To this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return v.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop default scroll action write this:

```
gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    return true;
} else {
    return v.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```